# Inheritance in Unreal C++. "GetOwningActor" doesnt return type "AMyPlayer"

Tags: c++, unreal-4, unreal, blueprints

```
void UAnimInstance_Player_PnC::NativeUpdateAnimation(float DeltaSeconds)
{
    Super::NativeUpdateAnimation(DeltaSeconds);

    APlayer_PnC* owningActor = GetOwningActor();

    if (owningActor != nullptr)
    {

    }
}
```

I realise this is more of a C++ type question than game dev specific, however I have noticed when I ask on Stack Overflow I get a C++ answer which is often not compatible with Unreal Engine way of doing C++.

I may be wrong, but I thought a child class has an "is a" relationship with its parent classes. So I thought that if I have `APlayer_PnC : public ACharacter` (which ACharacter is of course extending APawn , and then AActor), I would be able to 'find' it using the `GetOwningActor` function.

It gives the error `AActor* cannot be used to initialize type APlayer_PnC*` . I get it that I can just change that to AActor, but I need a variable that is part of the APlayer class.

What can I do to get access to a public variable in my `APlayer_PnC` instance.

The function I posted above is located in my custom AnimInstance class, which I have set my Player Blueprint to use and have re-parented the Anim Blueprint to my AnimInstance, but the variables do not show up.

I can post the full code if that will be of use, let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Are you not missing a cast here? Every `APlayer_PnC` is an `AActor` (so you can assign a value of type `APlayer_PnC` to a variable of type `AActor` without an explicit cast), but not every `AActor` is an `APlayer_PnC` (so the return value from `GetOwningActor` might *not* be an `APlayer_PnC` at runtime, and so you need a bit of code to validate that it is before assigning). I'm not an expert in Unreal, but that looks to me like general C++, not something gamedev-specific.

Comment: many thanks for the super quick help guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GetOwningActor returns an Actor.  You need to cast to your specific class.

In this case: APlayer_PnC* owningActor = Cast<APlayer_PnC>(GetOwningActor());

Comment: Thank you so much. I had tried it with 'static_cast<>' and it didn't work.